# CMakeTools extension was unable to initialize: Error: Invalid backend promise [See output window for more details]

Tags: c++, c, cmake, visual-studio-code, azure-iot-sdk

I have installed the latest CMake extensions into Visual Studio code V1.16.0 and I am unable to get the extension to work as I get the **"CMakeTools extension was unable to initialize: Error: Invalid backend promise [See output window for more details]"** error when clicking on configure.  I have searched various sources but cannot find any answers that allow me to get the extension working and my code building.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you open the `CMakeLists.txt` or the folder containing the `CMakeLists.txt`? Only the later works with the extension.

Comment: @Florian; Yes, I am trying to build one of the azure iot c sdk client samples.  the comes with a cmakelists.txt, hence the reason for requiring the cmake extensions to work